# InverseRelationShadowVariable for field of PlanningVariable

Tags: optaplanner

I have model for planning schedule of events. 
PlanningEntity Event has PlanningVariable Slot and Slot has two properties FullTimeSlot and RoomSlot.
I hasn't FullTimeSlot and RoomSlot in Event as different PlanningVariables because they are dependent on each other in a complicated way, and I combine it in one variable Slot.
I want to have ShadowVariable with List of Events in FullTimeSlot. And I do it with

- Add property FullTimeSlot in Event and CustomShadowVariable for this Property that depends on Slot
- Add property List of Event in FullTimeSlot and @InverseRelationShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "FullTimeSlot") on it

When I run solver I get an exeption
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The entity (custis.modeus.commonAutoScheduler.model.FullTimeSlot@6c84ad0e) was never added to this ScoreDirector.
Maybe that specific instance is not in the return values of the PlanningSolution's entity members ([EventList, FullTimeSlotList]).

I think it is because of FullTimeSlot @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty clone in solution, but property FullTimeSlot in Slot didn't clone.

But I dont understand how to do this case.

Code on Kotlin.

```
@PlanningEntity
class Event {
    @SerialName("id") @PlanningId
    var Id: Long = 0

    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "slotRange")
    lateinit var SlotList: ArrayList<Slot>

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = arrayOf("slotRange"), nullable = false)
    var Slot: Slot? = null

    @CustomShadowVariable(
        variableListenerClass = SlotVariableListener::class,
        sources = [PlanningVariableReference(variableName = "Slot")]
    )
    var FullTimeSlot: FullTimeSlot? = null
}

class SlotVariableListener : VariableListener<Event> {
    override fun beforeEntityRemoved(scoreDirector: ScoreDirector<*>?, entity: Event?) {
    }

    override fun afterVariableChanged(scoreDirector: ScoreDirector<*>?, entity: Event?) {

        if (entity != null) {
            scoreDirector!!.beforeVariableChanged(entity!!, "FullTimeSlot");
            entity!!.FullTimeSlot = entity.Slot?.FullTimeSlot
            scoreDirector!!.afterVariableChanged(entity!!, "FullTimeSlot");
        }
    }

    override fun beforeEntityAdded(scoreDirector: ScoreDirector<*>?, entity: Event?) {
    }

    override fun afterEntityAdded(scoreDirector: ScoreDirector<*>?, entity: Event?) {
    }

    override fun afterEntityRemoved(scoreDirector: ScoreDirector<*>?, entity: Event?) {
    }

    override fun beforeVariableChanged(scoreDirector: ScoreDirector<*>?, entity: Event?) {
    }
}
```

Comment: If its indeed a solution clone problem, adding `@DeepPlanningClone` on the correct class, field or getter, would fix it. Don't add that too much though.

Comment: I added @DeepPlanningClone on fields Slot and FullTimeSlot, but nothing changed. I think it is because of optaplanner clone PlanningEntity and field with '''@DeepPlanningClone''' independent and cloned solution has two different objects: one for entity FullTimeSlot and another for field FullTimeSlot in Event entity. Do I understand correctly? And if so, the only way is to implement own SolutionCloner?